# Weighted LRU cache. Is there a name for this methodology?

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures

Say I have an app that's trying to relate a string with an int. There are many strings and I want to keep a list of the top N that have occurred.

For example say the strings looked like this:

```
item 0 = "Foo"
item 1 = "Foo"
item 2 = "Boo"
item 3 = "Boo"
item 4 = "Bar"
item 5 = "Sar"
```

Say my cache has a cap of 3. Here's how I want it to behave:

```
item 0 = TryGet "Foo" - Add. "Foo" occurrences = 1
item 1 = TryGet "Foo" - return. "Foo" occurrences = 2
item 2 = TryGet "Boo" - Add. "Boo" occurrences = 1
item 3 = TryGet "Boo" - return. "Boo" occurrences = 2
item 4 = TryGet "Bar" - Add. "Bar" occurrences = 1
item 5 = TryGet "Sar" - At capacity. Remove elem with lowest occurrences, "Bar". Add "Sar"
```

So each current cache item gets a weight and on discovery of a new item when at capacity, we toss out the element with the lowest number of get occurrences. Is there a name for this kind of caching algorithm?

EDIT:
I was looking for Least-Frequently Used

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least-Frequently_Used_.28LFU.29

Comment: Isn't this precisely what [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_Recently_Used_.28LRU.29) (the term you yourself use) means?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: The OP's desired cache uses a Least Frequently Used eviction policy. An LRU cache evicts the least *recently* used.

Comment: You're looking for an LFU (Least Frequently Used) cache:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least-Frequently_Used_.28LFU.29

Comment: Ahhh Least Frequent Used. I read that page and skimmed right over that one too. Thanks Jim! Many kudos

Comment: You should add your own answer and close the question to avoid unnecessary efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for Least-Frequently Used